# How do I configure my grails app to skip preprocessing images?

Tags: grails

I've been asked to remove any images duplicated in the war file our grails app is packaged in. The documentation suggests this is possible via the `grails.assets.excludes` property in Config.groovy, but it doesn't clearly state how this property is supposed to work.

Here's what the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) says:

> Optionally, assets can be excluded from processing if included by your require tree. This can dramatically reduce compile time for your assets. To do so simply leverage the excludes configuration option:
>
> grails.assets.excludes = ["tiny_mce/src/*.js"]

The example is totally unclear to me. I've tried several permutations of this expression with no success; image assets continue to be preprocessed, causing duplicates of all of them in the resulting war file. Here are a few settings I've tried:

```
grails.assets.excludes = ["tiny_mce/src/*.jpg", "tiny_mce/src/*.jpg"]
grails.assets.excludes = ["<app_name>/src/*.jpg", "<app_name>/src/*.jpg"]
grails.assets.excludes = ["/images/*.jpg", "/images/*.png"]
grails.assets.excludes = ["**/*.jpg", "/images/**"]
```

What am I missing? How do I tell the asset pipeline to skip precompiling images?

Comment: I'm really surprised `"**/*.jpg"` isn't working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
grails.assets.excludes = ["**/*.jpg","**/*.png"]
```

I can't get any rule based on `images/` to work...

Comment: Apparently some bad conf data got into GGTS or somewhere in the Grails project. I had to blow away my dev box and start over, then to my surprise this config line started working. Yay.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and I also have unexpected behavior as well. This looks like a bug with the asset-pipeline.